# Concurrency in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to sequentially execute two **MYSQL** queries submitted from two different computers or locations at exactly same time to the **wampserver** ? I am using **PHP** to execute the **MYSQL** query. 
actually, I am trying to assign unique pc number to student for a particular time.But if two students are accessing the same system and trying to book system number exactly at the same time then same pc number is assigned to both students for the same time which is not correct . please say how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [auto_increment](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp) feature from mysql. It will make sure your field gets a unique ID when a new row is created.